# Get a specific TestSuite by Id using the TFS API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to get a specific TestSuite using the TFS API for a TestPlan.

The TestSuite could exist anywhere within a TestSuite hierarchy, so, of course I could write a recursive function.  I want something more efficient however.

Is there a method I am missing, or maybe a query that I could write?

Answer (score 5):

If you already know the `testSuiteId` things are quite straightforward. You only need to know the name of your TeamProject `teamProjectName`:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

namespace GetTestSuite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
           int testSuiteId = 555;
           const string teamProjectName = "myTeamProjectName";

           var tpc =
                TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
                    new Uri("http://tfsURI"));

           var tstService = (ITestManagementService)tpc.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
           var tProject = tstService.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);

           var myTestSuite = tProject.TestSuites.Find(testSuiteId);            
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't, you probably need to go for a solution similar to the one presented [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/07/06/tfs-api-part-27-test-plans-test-suites-test-cases-mapping.aspx) (it's a S.Raiten post), where recursion does come into picture. Access to a `testPlanId` is assumed:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

namespace GetTestSuite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int testPlanId = 555;
            const string teamProjectName = "myTeamProjectName";

            var tpc =
                TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
                    new Uri("http://tfsURI"));

            var tstService = (ITestManagementService)tpc.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            var tProject = tstService.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);

            var myTestPlan = tProject.TestPlans.Find(testPlanId);
            GetPlanSuites(myTestPlan.RootSuite.Entries);                
        }

        public static void GetPlanSuites(ITestSuiteEntryCollection suites)
        {
            foreach (ITestSuiteEntry suiteEntry in suites)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(suiteEntry.Id);
                var suite = suiteEntry.TestSuite as IStaticTestSuite;
                if (suite != null)
                {
                    if (suite.Entries.Count > 0)
                        GetPlanSuites(suite.Entries);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```